# GWT: Best way to Setsize of Buttons/Design Buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

Google Web Toolkit is a nice thing. I just have some problems with the designing. Lets start with the buttons: every browsers shows me a different look of a button.

Here Firefox: http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/3259/22957182.jpg
Here the Internet Explorer: http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/9310/32392601.jpg

The Code is always the same:

```
Button btnTest = new Button("Test");
        layoutPanel.add(btnTest);
        layoutPanel.setWidgetLeftWidth(btnTest, 58.0, Unit.PX, 87.0, Unit.PX);
        layoutPanel.setWidgetTopHeight(btnTest, 238.0, Unit.PX, 25.0, Unit.PX);
```

I can use btnTest.setSize... extra but it wont change the problem. I dont understand that. I need a website where the buttons (and everything else) looks normal on the IE.

Thats why i ask: are there different ways to design a button in gwt? Because to use a normal gwt button is buggy (see the pictures). What kind of tricks are the "skilled" people using with gwt?

i mean gwt = java to javascript , these buttons (an everything else) are javascriptbuttons or? i have no idea about javascript, but there is a way to make buttons which looks on IE the same like on firefox or?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Button class uses the browser's native button implementation. For more fine grained control over the appearance of buttons extend CustomButton with the exact faces you want.

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CustomButton.html

---

I'm not aware of a specific tutorial but my code looks something like this:

public class WVButton extends CustomButton {

```
public WVButton() {
    super();
    this.setStylePrimaryName("WV-Button");
}
```

Then the CSS file has

.WV-Button{}

.WV-Button-up-hovering{}

.WV-Button-up-disabled{}

and so on.

Each of which defines background-image:url("") of that face.

Comment: Hi Gottfried. Thank you for the answer. I have no idea how to extend a CustomButton with an "exact face i want". Are there some tutorials for that? Thank you.